# jQuery radio button hidden input value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio button that allows a user to select an option, for this I have made a hidden input to hold a value depending on this choice.

The form is as follows:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for='radio1'>Select this?&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type='checkbox' id='radio1' name='radio1' />

    <input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

And the jQuery like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#radio1").on("click", function () {
            var value1 = $("#value1").value;
            if ($("#radio1").attr("checked") == 'checked') {
                value1.val("true");
            }
            else {
                value1.val("false");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong where or how to fix it, can someone point me the right way?

Comment: What's actually going wrong for you? What does the code do?

Comment: The code is to say, { if the radio is checked, say this, else, say that }, but in the debugger in VS, the click event of the radio button does not fire anything to say { change the value of value1 to "true" OR "false" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the value of the checked property

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radio1").on("click", function () {
        $("#value1").val(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wfumc7mk/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.value` to the `value1`

```
var value1 = $("#value1"); // Don't need `.value` here

if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
    value1.val("true");
} else {
    value1.val("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running code

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#radio1").on("click", function() {

       if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
         alert($("#radio1").attr("checked", true).is(":checked"));
       } else {
         alert($("#radio1").attr("checked", false).is(":checked"));
       }
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='radio1'>Select this?&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='radio1' name='radio1' />

<input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
```